# System Clone to a new RAID1 Array

Tags: restore, clone, raid-1, easeus-todo-backup

I have a Lenovo ThinkServer TS440 system. It has a Win10 system. Two SSD drives in RAID1 array were setup. One of them just failed. I removed that one physically, removed the RAID1 in BIOS, and now the computer boots and runs fine--for the most part: Now the system is randomly logging me out or worse, restarting on it's own. Not sure this is related to the RAID1 removal or not.

Anyway, I have just ordered two SSDs and I'd like to Clone the existing system onto them. And here are some tools available:

1) I have a license for EaseUS ToDo Backup which is creating system backups in a NAS drive; the software can also 'Clone' to other drives.

2) I have an external USB drive which I can use to Clone from the current OS.

So what should be I do? I am thinking of:

1) Put the two new drives in the system and let BIOS create a RAID1; this will wipe them off--but of course there is nothing there yet.
2) Use the WinPE drive to boot and then make it do a 'restore' from the NAS to the RAID1 drive.

I am not sure this will work? Any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: You can’t usually just remove one drive and then disable RAID and still be able to use the other drive. It seems you were able to. With that said, if the computer is giving you problems, cloning the existing system to a new RAID 1 array is not going to fix that. Are you trying to fix the problem with your computer now, or are you just trying to get back on to a new RAID 1 array? And side question, why didn’t you just replace the SSD that failed originally? Sounds like you might’ve had some corruption in your old array.

Comment: The old SSDs were of smaller size and one had failed and was replaced and now the other one also failed (or maybe the replacement itself failed). I lost faith in that brand. Plus needed a larger capacity ones. And, yes, I was surprised to see that removing the RAID1 in BIOS retained my OS--there was a false warning that it would 'delete' the data if RAID1 removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it all to work using the tools as in the Question above.

1) Inserted the two new SSDs in the tower and created a RAID1 array in BIOS.

2) Rebooted the computer using the EaseUS WinPE DVD

3) In the DVD's GUI menu, from top right Tools, selected `Windows Shell` Commands

4) Used DOS `DiskPart` commands to Format the SSD and assigned letter C

5) Repeated Step #2

6) Browsed for Recovery and selected a recent System Backup.

7) Did a Clone operation and selected System Transfer from the Advanced option

8) Rebooted fine into Windows 10. Did a quick check for programs, drives etc.

9) Used EaseUS Partition Manager Free version to expand the C drive to accommodate the larger new SSD drives.

10) Rebooted and all done!!

HTH